# How can I subtract from elements in an array with pointer notation?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a prompt asking me to declare and initialize an array of 4 doubles and to create a pointer to the array. Then I should add 30.0 to the second physical element of the array through the pointer via array notation. After, I should subtract 10.0 from the last array element through the pointer using pointer notation. Then I should reassign the pointer to the last element of the array.

I have tried figuring out how to subtract with pointer notation but no dice. I’m not following what needs to be done.

Here’s my code so far:

```
int main () {
    double arr[4] = {10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0};
    double *p = &arr;
    p[1] = 30.0; //array notation
    //code should go here for the subtracting ten part

    //code should go here assigning pointer to last element of array.
    //My idea of how this would look:
    p = (p + 3); // or 15.0
    //or:
    p = arr[3];
}
```

I tried doing something like (p+3) -=10.0 but I have a feeling that’s wrong.

What I think the outcome should be: my arr elements being {10.0, 30.0, 20.0, 15.0} and p pointing to last element of array.

Comment: `double *p = &arr;` is a type error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So array notation is really syntactic sugar over pointer arithmetic. In your code:

```
p[1] = 30.0;
```

Can also be written as

```
*(p + 1) = 30.0;
```

Similarly, if you want to "subtract 10.0 from the last array element through the pointer using pointer notation"

You would do this:

```
double *p = arr
*(p + 3) -= 10.0
```

**Explanation:**

When you are declaring an array you are declaring a series of values stored in contiguous memory (that means memory blocks next to each other). The reason you are able to access different elements in that array is that you know

- Where the array starts
- How far along you want to move

So really, array notation `arr[2]` (where `arr` is an array of `double`s) means "Go to the memory address of array `arr`, move along `2 * sizeof(double)`, then give us the value stored there. Funnilly enough, that's exactly what `*(p + 2)` means, only it's broken down - the bit inside the brackets means "move along 2", and the star (the "dereference operator") means give us the value.

Comment: I'd definitely just opt for `*(p + 3) -= 10.` in the last example, OP has already demonstrated they can use `-=`. It might also be worth talking about why `p = &arr` didn't work

Comment: p = &arr didn’t work? That’s weird. I am writing this code without having a method to test it out. I just got pen and paper. :)

Comment: @MayAthena not a problem. If you are happy with the answer could you press the green tick to accept it?

Regards the &arr - that's because the `arr` on its own points to the memory address of the first element of the array anyway, so the address operator is not necessary.

Comment: @Ben Wainwright so its unnecessary to put the reference operator? I’ll take it out. Thank you!

Comment: The "value" of a C-family array is a pointer to its first element.  `double *p = arr` declares p as a pointer-to-double and sets its value to `arr`'s value, which, since `arr` is an array of doubles, is a pointer to its first element. The C family is pass-by-value, which is why when you declare a function taking an array, what you get  is a function taking a pointer to the array's element type.

Comment: Ooooh okay. So I should only pass by reference if I were to, say, pass the array into a function that does the conversions for me. Then I would likely need to reference. But I also read that array is pretty much like a pointer. So I got a tad bit confused with how to write my code out bc the whole pointer, reference thing got me.